# Windows 10: How Do I Keep Sound From A Game Running While Minimised?

Tags: windows-10, audio, gaming

I'm often playing games and alt-tabbing out and thinking, this is actually quite annoying that the music stops playing... kind of disruptive if you constantly have the music stopping and starting all the time.

**Anyway is there any way to keep sound running from minimised windows?**

I found this thread but I didn't know what to do with it (it's from 2013 so I assume its about windows 8 or somesuch): http://us.battle.net/forums/en/wow/topic/7708990832

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For World of Warcraft specifically, there's a setting within the game just for that.  In other words, this isn't a windows setting.  It's a game setting.  So it doesn't matter which version of Windows you're using.

Comment: So there's no option in windows for doing this, it depends on the game?

Comment: @Maidenhair It is up to the developer if they want to keep the sound playing while their software is minimised or not. There are even some games that automatically pause itself as soon as it is no longer in focus (if you click outside the game window and lose focus). Unless you have some 3rd party software that can somehow trick the game to think it is still in focus - then no..